# Trying to limit the QPushbuttons per row in PyQt4 GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

i am adding 'n' number of pushbuttons into a QHBoxLayout. In a horizontal layout all the buttons arranged in a row and some go out of the screen. But i need only 7 buttons in a row. Is there a way?

```
class test(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(test, self).__init__(parent)
      self.test_btn = QtGui.QPushButton()
      self.test_btn.show()
      self.test_btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_fun)
      self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
      self.setLayout(self.layout)

  def btn_fun(self):
      for i in range(42): 
         btns = QtGui.QPushButton('btns %d' %i)
         self.layout.addWidget(btns)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = test()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: to me it is not clear what you are asking... Can you be more specific about what the result should look like?

Comment: sorry, since i am new to stackoverflow i cannot attach the screenshot of my problem. i need to restrict the qpushbuttons arrangement within the screen. if they are more in number, they have to be arranged in a new row.

Comment: You might be a new member, but you can provide us a working example. Consider [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to help you when you show us only three lines of code.

Comment: @neo_v Upload the image to the cloud and share the link here and I will edit your question and add that image.

Comment: @Matho : I have edited the code

Comment: so you want a grid of buttons with up to a maximum of 7 per row?

Comment: @csunday95 : yes exactly

Comment: What about a grid layout?

Comment: @Trilarion: grid layout works fine .thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case a QGridLayout is more appropriate. You can then specifically assign each button's row and column so that only a limited number is in each row.

```
class test(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.max_per_row = 7
        self.btn_fun()

    def btn_fun(self):
        for i in range(42):
            col = i % self.max_per_row
            row = i//self.max_per_row
            btns = QtGui.QPushButton('btns %d' % i)
            self.layout.addWidget(btns, row, col)
```